# Calling Salesforce REST API within Jitterbit

Tags: oauth, salesforce, jitterbit

I am having issues with connecting Jitterbit to Salesforce exposed REST API.

Generally, i would like to know if anyone has had successful experience doing the above, and if so, do you have and guidance / documentation ?

Hugely appreciated. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the REST API from Jitterbit.  But for that, you need to first get the session (either by the connector or by calling the login service).  Then call the specific REST API Endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP endpoint to connect Rest API .
Following is good example :

```
https://success.jitterbit.com/display/DOC/REST+Transformation+-+Sugar+CRM+-+Request+Session+Token
```

You can also import following jitterpack sample

```
https://success.jitterbit.com/display/DOC/oAuth+1.0a+with+Twitter
```

Answer (score 0):

I have succefully implemented Jitterbit for integrating local PostgreSQL database with the salesforce. I have created a web service using Jiterbit and called it from salesforce to fetch the data from my local database to the Salesforce.

If you would like any help about integration, I can help you.